# Mix generic and redefine methods, giving different return types, which can be compiled?

Tags: kotlin

Kotlin compiler doesn't allow redefine functions, for example:

```
fun tmp() = 1
fun tmp() = ""
```

And JVM-based languages have generic erasure, so following code can't be compiled.

```
class Test<T>(a: T)
fun Test<String>.myFun() = Test(1)
fun Test<Int>.myFun() = Test("")
```

But how about this, why it can be compiled?

```
class Test<T>
fun Test<String>.myFun() = 1
fun Test<Int>.myFun() = ""
```

Because of the generic erasure, the two functions have the same parameters, and just have different return types. This shouldn't be compiled because of the first example. Why it can be compiled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example, you are not trying to redefine a function. You are trying to define two separate functions. And while their signatures are different, they have another problem: conflicting overloads. The compiler wouldn't be able to distinguish which one you are calling, because the input parameters are exactly the same.

In the second example, the problem is matching signatures rather than conflicting overloads.

The last example is OK because you don't have matching signatures or conflicting overloads. When you use them, the compiler can distinguish which one you are calling using the generic types. This happens before type erasure so it isn't an issue.

Some confusion may arise from the term "method signature" being overloaded in the Java world. When talking about code you write and what the compiler can handle, return type **is not** part of the signature. But in the bytecode and in errors logged by the JVM, return type **is** part of the signature. If you try to do the third example in Java, it will complain about the methods having the same erasure. [Apparently, the Java 6 compiler did allow it, but it was considered a bug and fixed so you can't do it in Java 7](http://vanillajava.blogspot.com/2011/02/with-generics-return-type-is-part-of.html)+. I don't know the details for this imposed restriction, but Kotlin is more lenient here.